# Flutter : JPEG image is not loading from decoded base64string (Image.memory)

Tags: flutter, image, dart, base64, rendering

I'm getting the UserPic from API in base64 format. (So, I do not encode the image to base64.) Then I convert it to Image using base64Decode.

```dart
     String normalized = base64.normalize(encodedBase64);
     return Image.memory(base64Decode(normalized),height: 275, width: 255);
```

But I am getting the following error: `EncodingError: Failed to decode frame at index 0.`
After doing some research, I saw that the problem was related to the renderer. Using `html renderer` solved the problem but it also broke the display of other widgets. That's why I want to render with `canvaskit` by default. How can I solve the problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

***Encode Image Path to base64 String:***

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';
String imagepath = " /data/user/img.jpg"; 
//image path, you can get it with image_picker package

File imagefile = File(imagepath); //convert Path to File
Uint8List imagebytes = await imagefile.readAsBytes(); //convert to bytes
String base64string = base64.encode(imagebytes); //convert bytes to base64 string
print(base64string);
```

***decode base64 Image to Bytes:***

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:typed_data';
Uint8List decodedbytes = base64.decode(base64string); //decode base64 stirng to bytes

Image.memory(decodedbytes,height: 275, width: 255)
```

Comment: The problem is not actually decoding or encoding images, but rendering them. They already encoded image to base64 in backend side so I just call the that API to use base64 string. This [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/101524) has already been mentioned. So this is not the solution I'm looking for unfortunately. @Etornam